# Can't manage to work with comparing days

Tags: select, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench, date, where

In a table with persons and their birthdays, the ones whose birthday is in less than 7 days need to be displayed.

I found some answers on the Internet but they all are at least 5 years ago with DATEDIFF that has 3 arguments instead of 2 and that doesn't help me.

I've just begun to work with Mysql and Workbench so, please, just change my simple syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM list
WHERE
MONTH(ls_bday) = 1 OR (ls_bday) = 2
and dayofmonth(ls_bday) < dayofmonth(current_time()+8)
```

or to include something in:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ls_bday, current_date())
from list
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "with DATEDIFF that has 3 arguments instead of 2"  Have you searched solution for the right dbms???  Even if the solution is not for MySQL, how hard can it be to convert SQL Server DATEDIFF() to MySQL DATEDIFF()?  It's part of programmer's job to figure things out.

Comment: Not sure how is your research skill, but here's the difference.  SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: @Eric yes, I researched that, converted it, and saw those of your link but still cannot change the syntax to display what it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE DATEDIFF(ls_bday, CURRENT_DATE()) < 7
```

Comment: I am still getting the full table and not only the fields where bday is in less than 7 days...:/

Comment: @Com Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tested what is the result of `DATEDIFF(ls_bday, CURRENT_DATE())`?